# $http.get(url) not returning data

Tags: angularjs

I am building a service in angular and injecting the service in controller. I am trying to fetch data from json file and am using $http. however the data is not getting returned and i get undefined.

I am updating my code as per suggestion by @Phil

**Service.js**

```
;(function(app) {
    app.factory('authService', ['$log', '$http','$location', function($log, $http,$location) {

        var url = 'js/user.json';
        var authService= {};
        var userExist=null;

        authService.authenticate = function(userid) {
            var userobj = $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
                userExist = data
                console.log(data);
                return userExist;
                $log.info("Loaded users");
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $log.info(error);
                $log.info("No user exists");
                return error;
            })
             return userobj;
        }
        return authService;


    }]);
})(angular.module('userApp'));
```

**Controller.js**

```
;(function(app) {
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$log','$location','authService', function($scope,$log,$location,authService) {

    $scope.data={};
    $scope.getUsers = function()
    {
      userid = "123";
      $scope.data = authService.authenticate(userid);
      console.log($scope.data);
      return $scope.data ;
  }

}]) 
}(angular.module('userApp')));
```

**index.html**

```
 <div class="main" ng-controller="Controller">

        <input type="button" name="btngetusers" ng-click="getUsers()"></input>

    </div>

    <script src ="js/app.js"> </script>
    <script src ="js/controller/Controller.js"> </script>
    <script src ="js/services/Service.js"> </script>
```

**user.json**
i have placed the json file under the js directory.

```
[
    {
        "UserId": "1",
        "FName": "Hice",
        "LastName": "Harry"
    },
    {
        "UserId": "2",
        "FName": "Andrew",
        "LastName": "Ads"
    }
]
```

The data is getting returned as undefined. what am i missing here?

**UPDATED CODE**

I am updating my code as per suggestion by @skubsi

**Service.js**

```
    ;(function(app) {
    app.factory('authService', ['$log', '$http','$location', function($log, $http,$location) {

        var url = 'js/user.json';
        var authService = {};
        var userExist=null;

        authService.authenticate = function(userid,success,error) {
            $http.get(url).success(function(data){
                success(data);
            })
            .error(error);

        };
        return authService;


    }]);
})(angular.module('userApp'));
```

**Controller.js**

```
;(function(app) {
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$log','$location','authService', function($scope,$log,$location,authService) {
    var self = this;
    this.data = null;

    this.getUsers = function(){

        function success(response){
            self.data = response;
        }

        function error(){
            console.log("error");
        }
        authService.authenticate(1,success,error);
    }


}]) 
}(angular.module('userApp')));
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController as main">
             {{main.data}}
            <input type="button" name="btngetusers" value ="Get User" ng-click="main.getUsers()"></input>

        </div>

    <script src ="js/app.js"> </script>
    <script src ="js/controller/MainController.js"> </script>
    <script src ="js/services/authenticate.js"> </script>
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend never using the `.success` or `.error` methods of the promise returned by `$http` in a service. Just `return $http.get(url);` in your service and deal with the promise resolution / rejection in your controller

Comment: If there is additional logic that belongs to the authenticate service, I don't. You should require and provide callback functions as parameters in your auth service. This way you can seperate concerns and call back the controller upon result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: your JSON is invalid, you can verify this yourself by entering the JSON you supplied in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

```
Parse error on line 2:
[    {        UserId: 123,       
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Secondly you pass a unknown service into your controller:

```
authenService
```

Then you should realize a promise is code that will run asynchronously, meaning that:

```
  userid = "123";
  $scope.data = authService.authenticate(userid);
  console.log($scope.data);
  return $scope.data ;
```

will not run synchronously. `console.log($scope.data);` Will be executed long before your authenticate method will be done. So you need to find a way to make your controller handle accordingly whilst keeping concerns separated. (and not falling into a [deferred-anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)).

You could for example add additional parameters to your authenticate function, which will enable the function to call back the original caller.

```
 authService.authenticate = function(userid, success, error) { //success and error are functions
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        //separation of concerns:
        //execute logic.. set flags, filter w/e belongs to your authentication process.
        success(data);
      })
      .error(error); //no processing required
  };
```

So that in your controller all that is left to do is calling the authService and providing it a way to set your data:

```
  this.getUsers = function() {
    //This will enable to set the response to your controllers data model.
    function success(response) {
      self.data = response;
      window.alert(response);
    }

    function error() {
      window.alert('shite happened');
    }

    authService.authenticate(1, success, error);
  };
```

Note that I have used the [controllerAs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) syntax instead of $scope. To prove this mechanism works I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/95lTbifpTh7GK9JbzsjW?p=preview) for you to investigate.

Answer (score 3):

Your authenticationService.authenticate method doesn't return anything.

Specifically, the service name is `authService` and you're calling `authenticationService.authenticate`.

Comment: i added the return value in the authenticationService.authenticate method. still the data returned is null.

Comment: typo rectified but still the data is returning null

Comment: you should return the promise. userExist is null by the time you return it, it will change in the future.

Comment: u mean i should return userobj instead of userExist

Comment: Yes, just return $http.get(...) as @Phil suggested in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82167/discussion-between-user2010243-and-andrew).